# Calculating values of an array by applying a SymPy function results in AttributeError

Tags: python, function, numpy, lambda, sympy

I have an array of numbers of which I want to calculate values with a simple equation.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

x_values = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
function = lambda x : 10*sym.sin(9*x)
function(x_values)
```

I get:

```
 AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'
```

Comment: Figured it out... Should have used "np.sin" instead of "sym.sin"

Comment: As noted in the comment, `10 * np.sin(9 * x_values)` works fine. If you wish to use `sympy` you can use `lambdify` following the example at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#lambdify

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `sympy.lambdify`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols("x")
x_values = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
function = sym.lambdify(x, 10*sym.sin(9*x), "numpy")
function(x_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a function

```
  import numpy as   np
    import sympy as sym
    x_values = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
    def function(x):
         lambda x : 10*sym.sin(9*x)
         return x

    print(function(x_values))
```

The code:http://tpcg.io/cBEnHu
or you can do this

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import sin
import pylab as pl
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import Function
from sympy import *
x_values = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)


function = lambdify(x, 10*sin(9*x))
print(function(x_values ))
```

The code:http://tpcg.io/cBEnHu